# Textures appear pure black, unless I pass an invalid value to texture uniform location

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

My program has been working perfectly so far, but it turns out that I've been lucky. I began doing some cleanup of the shader, because it was full of experimental stuff, and I had the following line at the end of the fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor = final_color * (texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st)*1.0 + texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].st)*1.0);
```

I attempted to clean it up and I had the following declared at the top:

```
uniform sampler2D tex, tex2;
```

Changing these lines to:

```
gl_FragColor = final_color * texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st;
```

and

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
```

actually broke the program (black screen), even though I am doing

```
GLuint tex_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id_, "tex");
glUniform1i(tex_loc, texture_id_);
```

in my main code. I'm sure it's a texture issue and not a glsl compiler error, because I can add `1.0` to the output and end up with a white silhouette of my mesh.

The strangeness begins when I change the lines in my shader to:

```
gl_FragColor = final_color * texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].st;
```

and

```
uniform sampler2D tex2;
```

but still retrieve the location for `tex`. The program works as it always has, even though inspecting the value of `tex_loc` in the debugger indicates an error. I'm not happy doing this, and now that I'm trying to load multiple textures, it will cause bigger headaches down the line.

I'm using VBOs, in interleaved format, to render the geometry. I'm passing in the vertex position, normal and texcoord this way.

There are other questions with the "black texture" issue, but they're using immediate mode calls and setting the wrong texture state. I tried changing the texture unit before supplying the arrays, with no success.

Here is as much relevant code as possible from the main program:

```
void MeshWidget::draw() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f + zoom_factor_);
    glRotatef(rotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(rotZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Auto centre mesh based on vertex bounds.
    glTranslatef(-x_mid_, -y_mid_, -z_mid_);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh_.num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));   //The starting point of the IBO
}


void MeshWidget::openMesh(const string& filename) {

    if (mesh_filename_ != filename) {

        clearMeshData(mesh_);

        glDeleteBuffersARB(1, &VertexVBOID);
        glDeleteBuffersARB(1, &IndexVBOID);

        ReadMsh(mesh_, filename);

        // Create buffer objects here.
        glGenBuffersARB(1, &VertexVBOID);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexAttributes)*mesh_.num_vertices, &mesh_.vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffersARB(1, &IndexVBOID);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uint16_t)*mesh_.num_indices, &mesh_.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexAttributes), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));   //The starting point of the VBO, for the vertices
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexAttributes), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));   //The starting point of normals, 12 bytes away
        glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexAttributes), BUFFER_OFFSET(24));   //The starting point of texcoords, 24 bytes away

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);

        if (startup_done_) updateGL();
    }
}

void MeshWidget::openTexture(const string& filename) {

    size_t dot = filename.find_last_of('.');
    string ext(filename, dot, filename.size()); // 3rd parameter should be length of new string, but is internally clipped to end.

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id_);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id_);

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    if (ext == ".dds") {
        if (GLEE_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc) {

            texture_id_ = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename.c_str(), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, texture_id_, SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT);
            // SOIL takes care of calling glTexParams, glTexImage2D, etc.
            yflip_texture_ = true;

            } else {
                //std::cout << "S3TC not supported on this graphics hardware." << std::endl;
                // TODO: Error message in status bar?
            }

    } else {

        QImage tex(filename.c_str());
        tex = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(tex);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex.width(), tex.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bits());

        yflip_texture_ = false;

    }

    updateUniforms();

    if (startup_done_) updateGL();
}

void MeshWidget::updateUniforms() {

    GLuint texture_flip_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id_, "yflip");
    glUniform1f(texture_flip_uniform, float(yflip_texture_ * 1.0f));

    GLuint tex_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id_, "tex");
    glUniform1i(tex_loc, texture_id_);
}
```

And my shaders (there's still some junk in here because I was experimenting, but nothing that affects the output):

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir, eyeVec;
uniform float yflip;

void main()
{   
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    vec3 vVertex = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);

    lightDir = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vVertex);
    eyeVec = -vVertex;

    gl_TexCoord[0].x = gl_MultiTexCoord0.x;
    gl_TexCoord[1].x = gl_MultiTexCoord1.x;

    if (yflip == 1.0) {
        gl_TexCoord[0].y = 1 - gl_MultiTexCoord0.y;
        gl_TexCoord[1].y = 1 - gl_MultiTexCoord1.y;
    } else {
        gl_TexCoord[0].y = gl_MultiTexCoord0.y;
        gl_TexCoord[1].y = gl_MultiTexCoord1.y;
    }

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir, eyeVec;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main (void)
{

    vec4 texel = texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    vec4 final_color =
(gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) + 
(gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);

    vec3 N = normalize(normal);
    vec3 L = normalize(lightDir);

    float lambertTerm = dot(N,L);

    if(lambertTerm > 0.0)
    {
        final_color += gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * 
                   gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * 
                   lambertTerm; 

        vec3 E = normalize(eyeVec);
        vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
        float specular = pow( max(dot(R, E), 0.0), 
                     gl_FrontMaterial.shininess );
        final_color += gl_LightSource[0].specular * 
                   gl_FrontMaterial.specular * 
                   specular;    
    }

    gl_FragColor = final_color * texel;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> glUniform1i(tex_loc, texture_id_);

The second parameter should specify ID of a texture unit(hint: [glActiveTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) sets the currently active texture unit), not ID of particular texture object.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean I should pass in `GL_TEXTURE0` in place of `texture_id_`?

Comment: Yes. Or you can just pass 0, as noted in the glActiveTexture link.

Comment: According to my copy of OpenGL SuperBible, it's supposed to be `0` and not values in the enum, which caused a crash when I tried it just now. Thanks!